# React Native not being suggested in VSCode

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working on react native and [I cannot have RN's component as suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9cuD.png). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can give this package a try.

```
npm install --save @types/react-native
```